# What are Sage Beans in Dragon Ball Super?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

In episode 6 of DBS, Goku says he got a "Sage Bean" from King Kai. What exactly are Sage Beans? Are they the same as Korin's Senzu Beans?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sage Beans are simply another name for Senzu Beans, they are not a separate category of power-items.

The kanji for senzu (仙豆) is simply 'wizard' or 'hermit' (仙) and a generic 'bean' (豆). As such, it is only a broad name, and could be variously translated as Wizard/Hermit/Sage Beans. The wizard/sage/etc is possibly a reference to Korin who grows them, since he is both brilliant and reclusive.